# Delete records by username DAO/hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, dao

how do I remove all records associated to one user, for example I want to remove 5 records in my database that owner is currently logged in user.
Here is my code:

```
public void deleteOrders() {

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();
    String user = auth.getName(); // get logged in username
    getHibernateTemplate().delete(
            "FROM " + Orders.class.getName() + " WHERE username='" + user
                    + "'");
}
```

Im trying something like this but it fails and I can't move on. How to do it right?

Comment: If it fails, try to make it work. The only thing we can say with so few details is that you should use parameterized queries instead of concatenation. AT least show us the code of the entity and the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`HibernateTemplate.delete()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#delete%28java.lang.Object%29) takes an entity instance to delete as argument. It doesn't take a HQL query.

Use `bulkUpdate()` to execute a delete query. Or even better, forget about HibernateTemplate, which is deprecated, and use the Hibernate API directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's probably not going to work, because `class.getName()` includes the package path, but if your class name is the same as the table name, `getSimpleName()` might work:

```
"FROM " + Orders.class.getSimpleName() + " WHERE ..."
```

However, I would be inclined to do something like this:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("delete from orders where ...").execute();
```

Comment: You can put the fully quelified name of an entity in a HQL query, AFAIK.